# Gerrit & Phabricator review

Tags: gerrit, phabricator

Has anyone done a review between [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) and [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)? 
I am looking out for a review tool and want to settle on one based on:

- Ease of use
- Comprehensiveness in features
- Activity by the community
- and adoption

Edit: I use **Git**

Answer (score 12):

I've tried to compare them and these are the most prominent differences I've found

**Gerrit**

- +Acts as a repository so you push to it and it creates a review issue of your commit
- +No commit ever gets through with out review as it is impossible to forget to create review issue
- -Works only with git
- -Can't handle post commit review (auditing) at all.

**Phabricator**

- +Handles git, svn and hg
- +Let's you create post commit review of commits through magic (herald)
- +Integrates loads of tools
- -Integrates loads of tools (yes, that is both good and bad)
- -Pre commit code review is optional. You send diff to Differential and once that is approved you push to your repo. In my opinion that isn't very user friendly but might be manageable if you keep each issue/future commit in it's own branch.

Comment: One additional pro with Gerrit is you don't need to use additional command line tools push code. where as with Phabricator we have use stuff like  `Arc`

Comment: Right. And if you skip arc (forget it) you will just bypass code review.

Comment: +1 Phabricator for single review of a feature branch. Gerrit discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/mUYbUvpMFNY and development https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/5oRra_tLKMA of same

Comment: -1 Phabricator for single review of a feature branch. It would be indeed nice if it supported diff of each commit in the feature branch, but it only supports diff of the entire feature branch. This breaks the purpose of splitting the feature in several commits (make review easier). There is a feature request in Phabricator issue tracker to support diffs of each patch in a patch set, but it is stalled for a long time.

Comment: You can configure Phabricator to refuse commits without review, so it's *not* optional: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662723/phabricator-restrict-git-push

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer - I'm not very familiar with Phabricator.

It seems like Phabricator includes many more tools than just code-review.  Bug tracking, source browsing, wiki - these are things which Gerrit doesn't include but instead is designed to work with external tools.

I'm not sure which SCM tool(s) Phabricator works with.  Gerrit only supports git.

The Gerrit community is very active - we are just now wrapping up a 1-week hack-a-thon between a dozen of the most active developers.  Gerrit is used by lots of big companies and has a lot of backing.  Looking at the activity feed for Phabricator it also seems very active.

Gerrit's adaptation is largely being driven by Android.  Any company working on Android will likely set up a Gerrit instance, as that is what upstream Android uses.  In many cases Gerrit use will then spread throughout the company as they see all the benefits Gerrit provides (this is what happened at my company and several others).  Gerrit is also quickly growing outside Android shops at places like Wikimedia, QT, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Phabricator is nice but it's differential can't handle large commit [[Details]](http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Differential_User_Guide_Large_Changes.html) yet and show confusing error. Its really a big issue. Moreover, you should have clear concept about git, to use phabricator in a smooth way.

Comment: The referenced page says Differential/Phabricator will fail when created review is excessively large, greater than any amount a human would review. This doesn't sound like an issue at all.

Comment: I have a message properties file containing 15500 entries. How I can upload a commit which include a line change in that properties file? In my case, Phabricator fail in this point, where Gerrit successfully upload the difference.

Comment: That is a real issue you have. If I was in that situation, I'd (a) contribute to the open-source project, or (b) split up my file because Phabricator is that nice to use. My review queue somehow magically stays virtually empty which has never happened with any other tool.

Comment: If you run arc diff with --less-context option, it will only upload the difference.

Comment: I had this commit size issue with Phabricator when refactoring code (eg renaming or moving source code directory)

Answer (score 1):

Reasons I chose Phabricator:

- It works with SVN.
- Easy to install.

I'm not a linux person but I ran up an ubuntu image in a VM and installed Phabricator on that, along with svn etc

I haven't used gerrit but would have done if it worked with SVN. IMO it looks nicer (functionality-wise).

Comment: Could you help me in Installing Phabricator. I have install ed on ubuntu and working finr bit I am not able to figure it out how to connect with svn , how to set up acr and other utilities. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As I am working on Phabricator now, it has so many outstanding features cover from repository hosting to code review and then code commit. Phabricator is really a cool tool. And it has integration with Jira and many other tools. And also, the people who are working on it are very nice, every issues you raised up, they will get you very quickly.