# How to block git push before a review being accepted in phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I have been trying [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) platform for 2 days in that to use it in our team. Everything seem fairly great except one I don't know how to make it.

We want to add Code Review process to our work flow forcefully. So I config Differential. Then as a developer I can use Arcanist command line to send a diff to the web UI requiring someone else to review. Someone can also accept or deny it after reviewing. That is OK.

But me who should be waiting other's review acceptance before pushing my changes to the hosted repo, can do that with git push (not arc land or arc amend) without the acceptance. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Maybe this question might be better in the SuperUser Stack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662723 has two good answers to this same question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. A user either has push rights or he has none. One way would be to trust the committer not to push his things until the review was accepted. On the other hand you could drop the right to push and let the reviewer or an administrator land the patch.

One different (maybe little complicated) way might be to create some herald rules to prevent the push. But I am not sure if herald is flexible and powerful enough for that kind of job.

Comment: Herald rules are flexible and powerful enough to do this. See comment to original question by @Mukunda Modell.

Answer (score 4):

In the upstream we have Herald check for the presence of a Differential Commit, which you can send an embarrassing email, trigger an Audit, or whatever. Because we're a small team, we trigger an Audit (presuming those instances are generally emergencies and can be reviewed later). If the repository is also hosted by Phabricator, you can set a Policy on the repository to who has access to push to it. We use this to gate contributors. Frequent contributors can land reviewed code freely. New contributors have to have code landed by the upstream manually.