# How to restrict push to git repository if the commit is not accepted in Phabricator?

Tags: git, gitlab, phabricator, pre-commit-hook

I want to restrict users to push directly to git repository without pre-commit to Phabricator. Please suggest solutions to avoid push without pre-commit. I don't know how to write git hook for this.
Thanks in advance:)

[Herald rules applied example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGGCJ.png)

Herald rules not working. Arc land still pushes code.

Comment: You should probably use the Herald rules that are available in Phabricator. More information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662723/phabricator-restrict-git-push

Comment: I tried with herald rules. But it's not working for me. arc land allows landing without checking rules. and also how to restrict push from IDE?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about 2 things:

- Avoid commits from direct pushes without Diffs. This would reject creating a `post-push` workflow called `audit`

[image: Herald Rule Overview]
[image: Herald Rule Details]

- Make sure users create diffs with arcanist to start a `pre-push` workflow.
- Check if the config `differential.allow-self-accept` is set to `false`.
- Create a herald rule to add blocking reviewers to new diffs like: https://secure.phabricator.com/H65
- Change the push policy for your repositories you would like to restrict. For Example: https://secure.phabricator.com/source/phabricator/manage/policies/

> NOTE: This solution still works, I'm running this config for 2 years now ;)

Comment: I have updated the image with herald rules which i applied